# Why can't I see my tweets on the recipient's timeline?

Tags: twitter

I just set up my Twitter account, and even after reading almost everything on their "Help" page, I am still confused about tweeting the people I'm following. Let me explain:

I am following Richard Roeper. I wanted to send him a tweet saying something like, "I'm a huge fan". So I went to Richard's profile page, and clicked on the "Tweet To Richard Roeper" button. I wrote my tweet and sent it. But I can't see the tweet I sent to him on his timeline under "Tweets" or "Tweets and Replies". Where did it go? Did he get my tweet? Or does my tweet not show up on his timeline?

Answer (score 4):

When you look at his Twitter profile, the "Tweets" will show all of *his* tweets and retweets.  The "Tweets and Replies" will show all of *his* tweets, retweets, and replies to people.  You cannot see the tweets that people sent to him (including the one you wrote to him) on his profile.

However, you can search for tweets sent to him by using the Twitter [Advanced Search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced).  In the "To these accounts" box, type "richardroeper".  You can also put your username in the "From these accounts" box to only show the tweets you sent to him.  Then press Enter.  At the top of the results page, you might need to click on "All".

Answer (score 1):

Yes - he can see it, but you can't see all tweets related to him.

You can see your tweet related to him on your timeline. Or you can see his tweet related to 3rd person only if you both follow him.